# Speed issues with Google App Engine + Spring MVC + Annotations

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I am developing an application on GAE with spring MVC and using annotations. The application take a long time to load the first time and then it behaves well as long as I access the application. But then when I leave the application for a minute and then I access it again it is taking long time. I have read ppl having similar issues but did not talk about the solution. Has anyone had this problem and was able to fix it ?

One solution was stripping the annotations which I want to do as the last choice.

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

One way to speed up the initial loading of Spring would be to disable the `<context:component-scan base-package="app.controllers" />` line in your springapp-servlet.xml and manually specify all of the controllers in your application like this:

```
<bean id="rootController" class="app.controllers.RootController" ></bean>
<bean id="otherController" class="app.controllers.OtherController" ></bean>
```

I'm using Spring MVC on Google App Engine and have gotten loading requests down to ~3 seconds.

Comment: Kyle, so basically, don't do any component scanning. 3 seconds for approx how many controllers?

Answer (score 1):

GAE kills you app if nobody clicks it for a minute.

Comment: i figured that but I want no know if there is any solution for not doing that.

Comment: use cron.xml to ping yourself every minute?

Comment: Cron (or similar) is not a great solution because it'll likely have a temporary effect as Google combats everyone trying to do that, which they will if they want to keep costs down for everyone else.

Comment: added a small cron job, which is keeping the application alive but as u said this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's a precompilation-enabled property in the latest version that you can use to speed this up somewhat. See [this article](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/12/request-performance-in-java.html) on why. It might not solve runtime-startup issues but I'm hoping the annotations are compile-time.

> You can enable it for your application
>   by adding precompilation-enabled to
>   your appengine-web.xml:
>
> ```
> <precompilation-enabled>true</precompilation-enabled>
> ```